# TYPO3: Render plugin to a mapped area (TemplaVoila)

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I would like to create a image slider plugin through `KickStart` Extension. I have already installed `TemplaVoila` and mapped the area for the slider.

So how to connect my plugin to that mapped  area.

I can insert static text in mapped area like this

```
lib.slidercontent = TEXT
lib.slidercontent.value = Slider Images!!!
```

then how do I render my slider plugin in to `lib.slidercontent`.

And what kind of plugin it should be? like `Backend`, `Frontend`, `Frontend-plugin`.. etc.

```
I want to show this slider in all pages
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an extension and add FE plugin in it
2. in your TS template add:

   ```
   lib.slidercontent < plugin.tx_myslider_pi1
   ```
3. in `TemplaVoila` add new field in `DataStructure`

   - name ie. : `field_slider`
   - Element preset: `TypoScript Object Path`
   - After adding it use `Typoscript` section and in  `Object Path` field add: `lib.slidercontent`
4. Save it

   - Save the field in DS,
   - map the field to some templates' block,
   - save the DS,
   - clear the cache,check the FE